# .htaccess and codeigniter, error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

so i had 404 error with all my codeigniter things while it works very well in local but when uploaded on public production on 1and1 shared hosting, nothing work. I get 404 errors.

my settings are as follow :

```
www.myname.com/subfolder1/
```

<= here is my codeigniter root, yes i want codeigniter to be one level after the regular "root" / level

i have this .htaccess in this subfolder1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if i try the regular codeigniter "url":

```
http://www.myname.com/subfolder1/index.php/admin/login
```

i notice it goes to :

```
http://www.myname.com/admin/user/login
```

may be i have a problem there with the last rule, i tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/subfolder1/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

with no success.

my `config/config.php` has this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.myname.com/';
```

i tried to put there `http://www.myname.com/subfolder1` with no success.

as this site is still in test, because i am new to all this... i decide to put a login/password from the .htaccess, so i also have this first level .htaccess in the root `http://www.myname.com/` 
so can it be a problem? how can i still have this first level .htaccess with a working .htaccess for codeigniter? if yes, can someone explain me howto?

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /."
AuthUserFile /my/path/to/htpasswd
Require user testuser
```

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i finally understand what was my trouble => the rewriting should be :

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ subfolder1/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and yes, i needed to change the `base_url` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.myname.com/subfolder1/';
```

because without, none of the path (js/style) was ok.

Answer (score 0):

you also solved using this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder1/

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And your base_url will be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.myname.com/subfolder1/';
```

And remove index page from your config.php file 
It will be like this

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```